# Can't find the lowest value from percentage query

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I'm looking for the lowest value from percentage value from one subquery in PostgreSQL.

This is what I tried:

```
-- Objective, find lowest value from percent subquery to return only one row

WITH lowest_pct AS 
    (
        SELECT
              c2010.geo_name, -- Geographical name
              c2010.state_us_abbreviation AS state_name, --State abbreviation 
        
        -- p0010001 = total population for each county used in 2010 and 200
        -- Here, it's percentage change query
              ROUND(((CAST(c2010.p0010001 AS NUMERIC(8,1)) - c2000.p0010001) / c2010.p0010001)*100 , 1)
                AS pct_change
        
        FROM us_counties_2010 AS c2010 INNER JOIN us_counties_2000 AS c2000
        ON c2010.state_fips = c2000.state_fips
            AND c2010.county_fips = c2000.county_fips
                AND c2010.p0010001 <> c2000.p0010001
        ORDER BY pct_change ASC
    )
    
    SELECT 
        geo_name,
        state_name,
        MIN(pct_change)
        
    FROM lowest_pct;
```

The result:

> ```
> ERROR: ERROR: Column 'low_pct.geo_name' must appear in GROUP BY clause or must be used in an aggregate function
> LINE 17: geo_name,
>          ^
> SQL Status: 42803
> Character: 459
> ```

How to fix this?

Comment: This will fix the issue: GROUP BY geo_name, state_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Frank already hinted, you need a `GROUP BY` clause in the outer `SELECT`.
While being at it, I simplified / fixed a couple of other minor things:

```sql
SELECT geo_name, state_name, min(pct_change) AS min_pct_change
FROM  (
   SELECT c2010.geo_name
        , c2010.state_us_abbreviation AS state_name
        , round(((c2010.p0010001 - c2000.p0010001) * 100 / c2010.p0010001)::numeric , 1) AS pct_change
   FROM   us_counties_2010 AS c2010
   JOIN   us_counties_2000 AS c2000 USING (state_fips, county_fips)
   WHERE  c2010.p0010001 <> c2000.p0010001
   ) lowest_pct
GROUP  BY geo_name, state_name  -- !!!
ORDER  BY min_pct_change, state_name, geo_name;
```

While working with `round(expr, 1)`, there is no need (no point really) to *also* cast to `numeric (8,1)` before rounding. The result is type `numeric` (without modifier) either way.

No need for a CTE. A subquery is cheaper, especially in Postgres 11 or older.

`ORDER BY` in the CTE (or subquery) is pointless. That order may or may not be carried over after the aggregate in the outer `SELECT`. I added `ORDER BY min_pct_change, state_name, geo_name` to the outer `SELECT`. (You might want `ORDER BY min_pct_change DESC ...`?)